# Read and aggregate CSV files on Mule 4

Tags: csv, file, mule, mule4

I have several CSV files with below format:

```
ID;NOTE;FISCYEAR;MONTH;CURRENCY;CURRENCY_2;NUMBERS;NUMBERS_2;CASH
177204930;"Something ""relevant"" date 01.03.07";2021;1;EUR;599;599000;599;"599,00 EUR"
175618258;"Address; 48ct xpto.";2021;1;EUR;1;1000;0.35;"0,35 EUR"
```

Where I must read and aggregate them into one payload to process (with `batch`) later. I must read ~50 files, with ~33MB each.

However, `File List Operator` don't have `outputMimeType` attribute, as in `On New or Updated File`, where I can configure in `MIME Type` tab the `separator=;` `escape="` and `streaming=true`. I can't use this one as I can only read one file per time with it.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using set variable to assign the payload of each file -which is a lazy stream to the contents- to a variable and in the same operation set the mimeType attribute.

```
<file:read>...
<foreach>
   <set-variable variableName="contents" value="#[payload]" mimeType="application/csv..." />
   <!-- process the file contents here as vars.contents -->
```

Comment: work like a charm :) I changed `foreach` to `parallel-foreach` to improve performance.